# OSX + Java + OpenSSL + org.apache.commons:commons-crypto = SegFault in OpenSslNative:initIDs

Tags: java, macos, openssl, apache-commons

I had a simple Java class using Apache:commons-crypto to do encryption/decryption that was SegFaulting on me.

On OSX, I used Homebrew to install the latest OpenSSL to use.

Tracing down the issue, it occurred in the OpenSslNative:initIDs JNI linked native code somewhere. I found the c code here:

`https://github.com/apache/commons-crypto/blob/master/src/main/native/org/apache/commons/crypto/cipher/OpenSslNative.c`
`https://github.com/apache/commons-crypto/blob/master/lib/include/config.h`

Scanning through the code, I found that on OSX, the "libcrypto.dylib" is referenced. That library was correctly linked into the /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib directory.

Answer (score 0):

Confident that the libs were not found, I updated my ~/.zshrc to include

`export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib"`

My code worked again now that the library could be found.

If there is a better way to make this work, I would be interested in knowing it.